# How to understand the operator "\" in define macro?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm using a micro controller STM32f100RB. In one of head files ,there's something I can not understand.The code is as following.Can anybody tell me What the symbol "\" is ? Is it an operator?How to understand it?

I'm a newbie here.If anything I did is not proper ,please let me know.
Thank you.

```
#define IS_GPIO_ALL_PERIPH(PERIPH) (((PERIPH) == GPIOA) || \
                                    ((PERIPH) == GPIOB) || \
                                    ((PERIPH) == GPIOC) || \
                                    ((PERIPH) == GPIOD) || \
                                    ((PERIPH) == GPIOE) || \
                                    ((PERIPH) == GPIOF) || \
                                    ((PERIPH) == GPIOG))
```

Comment: Its showing the remaining of the macro will be in the next line

Comment: Before blaming it on your microcontroller it's always worth looking it up a language reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backslash just tells the pre-processor to treat the next line as if it is on this same line. This is required since macros are defined on a "single line"... so this lets multiple lines be coalesced into one.

Note that in some (all?) pre-processors, the backslash *must* be the final character on the line... including whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

It means, that the macro continues on the next row, as macros are required to be defined on one row (the `\` actually "escapes" the symbol(s) for new row).

Basically, you macro is the same as:

```
#define IS_GPIO_ALL_PERIPH(PERIPH) (((PERIPH) == GPIOA) || ((PERIPH) == GPIOB) || ((PERIPH) == GPIOC) || ((PERIPH) == GPIOD) || ((PERIPH) == GPIOE) || ((PERIPH) == GPIOF) || ((PERIPH) == GPIOG))
```

Which, as you can see, it's harder for reading and understanding than the one, posted in your question.

Answer (score 2):

The [gcc documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/cpp/Initial-processing.html) states:

> A continued line is a line which ends with a backslash, \. The backslash is removed and the following line is joined with the current one. No space is inserted, so you may split a line anywhere, even in the middle of a word. (It is generally more readable to split lines only at white space.)

Answer (score 1):

\ is macro is nothing but we are just informing preprocessor that there is no new line next statement is also on the same line.....

when there is a big expression which cant be fit in one single line or if it fits than it is not unreadable than this \ is used. it removes at preprocessor stage.